# Let's add a tag for [metaballs]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Why is there no tag for [metaballs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metaballs)? Metaballs are a matter of discussion like anything else, and a very distinctive topic.

Comment: Added: [Why does Blender convert ALL of the metaballs to mesh and not only the selected object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242311/why-does-blender-convert-all-of-the-metaballs-in-the-scene-to-mesh-and-not-only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you couldn't yet create your own tags, I thought it would be useful to point out that there is a privilege earned at 1500 reputation *[Create New Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)*.

Anyone who has 1500+ reputation can create a tag simply by

> Enter[ing] a new tag with your question and it will be created. When creating your new tag, bear in mind that tags ...
>
> - must be no longer than 35 characters
> - must use the character set a-z 0-9 + # - .
> - on some sites, new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least 1 other question in a 6 month period.
> - meta tags, tags that cannot stand alone as the only tag on a question, are not allowed.

In addition to creating a tag, you will create a tag wiki entry that is initially blank.  Anyone can propose an edit to a tag wiki, but you have to have a reputation of 20,000 or more to approve such an edit.

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/1059900) contains a good discussion on how to edit a tag wiki entry.

Comment: Oh thank you! Now wondering why somebody downvoted my question. Poor frustrated people...